# Грамматическая основа

Tags: сказуемые, подлежащее

*Раз мы начали говорить, то лучше договорить все до конца.*

Какие 2 основы в этом предложении?

Comment: @Екатерина Сорина, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

мы начали говорить

лучше договорить